When I try to install any package with Homebrew, I get these permission denied errors and it can't install anything
When I try to install any package with Homebrew, I get these errors and it can't install anything.
Error: Permission denied @apply2files - /opt/homebrew/share/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-tabler-1.0.0-beta/node_modules/tabler/src/pages/_data/package.json

My question is if I can delete it manually, or if the folder is part of something on the system.

Thanks all, I deleted that folder, and I already managed to install things with homebrew
